# Writing 1D array to different columns in a CSV C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, csv, append, ofstream

I have a function that generates a 1D array of values. I want to store that array into a CSV file. Each time I call the function I would like to store this data into a new column in the CSV. Right now my code is semi-working, it is continually adding the new data array to my csv each time I call the function but it is adding it to the bottom of the same column. I would like the data to be stored in the next column instead of being added to the bottom of the first column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*** I have removed the section of the code that generates my standard_dev array ***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void standard_deviation_line(Mat image, int column_count) {

    int sum = 0;
    int standard_dev_col = 0;
    int i, j; 
    const int cols = 3840;
    int rows = image.rows;
    float standard_dev[cols];
    float mean[cols];

ofstream out("SD.csv", ios::app);
    for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        out << standard_dev[i] << endl;

    out.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the endl in your for loop, it outputs a linefeed.

ed: try this

```
template<typename Iter>
std::string join(Iter p0, Iter p1) {
    std::string result{};
    if(p0 != p1) {
        result = std::to_string(*p0++);
    }
    while(p0 != p1) {
        result += ',';
        result += std::to_string(*p0++);
    }
    return result;
}
```

then use it without the for loop like this:

```
out << join(standard_dev, standard_dev + cols) << '\n';
```

Comment: Might as well finish the answer off by telling the asker what they should output instead: a comma.

Comment: @user4581301 so when i replace the endl with a "," it just creates a single row in my csv. everything is overwritten and it does not print them out in columns like i wanted

Comment: Time to take things back a notch. How do you know when a row is finished?

Comment: @user4581301 for each pass through the for loop it creates a new row. first time i call the function it places all the values in column 0 and drops down a row for each value. The second time I call the function i want it to start in column 1.

Comment: as a temporary workaround i am just printing everything out in row 0 for the first time i call the function and then at the end of the function i do out << endl; which creates a new row so that the next time i call the function i am now starting in row 1. this is fine but i really want the data to be in columns

Comment: @colinodowd It is hard to write a CSV file column by column. A CSV file is a stream of text with each column separated by a comma and each row separated by a new line. To insert a new column you need to read a row from the source file and write that row to a new file up to the column you with to insert, you then write the new column value for that row, add a comma to separate, and then write out the rest of the columns in the source row. Then you get a new row from the source file. Repeat until done and then replace the source file with the new file.

Comment: This is whole orders of magnitude slower than building the whole matrix and writing it row by row.